# Bootstrap-select append option and select item

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I would like to append option into a bootstrap-select, and show it in the menu, the issue is how to show this value:

```
$('#' + data.field).append('<option value="' + data.supplierKey + '">' + data.supplierName + '</option>');
$('#' + data.field).selectpicker('val', data.supplierKey);
$('#' + data.field).attr('placeholder', data.supplierName);
$('#' + data.field).attr('title', data.supplierName);

/**
  And how can I change the name 'Supplier' inside <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">Supplier</div>
  NB: I do have 3 bootstrap-select on the same page.
**/

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); // refresh to show select
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and would like to share it with the rest:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); // refresh to show select
$('#' + data.field).selectpicker('val', data.supplierKey);
$('#' + data.field).attr('placeholder', data.supplierName);
$('#' + data.field).attr('title', data.supplierName);
```

I just placed the refresh option first then follow with the rest.